# How do I trace the response of this call in Swift Xcode?

Tags: swift

Data in the below call is nil so the call is failing:

```
        postRequest("/api/users/signup", params: params, headers: nil) { data in
            guard data != nil else {

                return completionHandler(nil, UsersStoreError.CannotSignup)
```

This is the postRequest function:

```
private func postRequest(_ url: String, params: Parameters?, headers: HTTPHeaders?, completion: @escaping([String:Any]?) -> Void) {
        let enc = JSONEncoding.default
        let url = AppConstants.ENDPOINT + url

        Alamofire
            .request(url, method: .post, parameters:params, encoding:enc, headers:headers)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch (response.result) {
                case .success(let data): completion((data as! [String:Any]))
                case .failure(_): completion(nil)
                }
        }
    }
```

How can I trace the response of this call?

Comment: What is `postRequest`? is that a function you've created or is part of some library?

Comment: @Chakeeel share code for `postRequest` method

Comment: Hey, I have edited OP to include it

Comment: add print statement before `switch` `print(response)` to check actual response from server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a breakpoint in the responseJSON block in your postRequest method and inspect/print the response parameter. That should give you information about the request and the response.

It's possible that the response isn't valid JSON. To check what you're actually getting back, add this to responseJSON (before your switch):

```
debugPrint(String(data: response.data!, encoding: .utf8))
```